# I need server for upload and download data

Tags: c#, file-upload, server, download

I need to upload and download some binary files i have created in program,and i have a problem.None of cloud storage works that way,and i will pay a server for myself when everything is finished but for now i need to test it like that.
I need server that can upload and download data that I send with link in C# using WPF graphic API.

Can you recommend me a good free server for test?

I tried using 000 and google cloud

It need to replace file on URL and keep the same URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft® Azure Free Account would be good option for trial work. The account also gets 12 months of free services.